# LTspice AC analysis extracting only the phase shift value at a certain frequency

Tags: ltspice, phase-shift

I am trying to extract the phase-shift value at a certain frequency in AC-analysis mode in LTspice.

```
.meas AC Ph_Shift FIND (V(out)/V(in)) WHEN FREQ=50
```

With the command above LTspice gives the answer line below in the log file:

```
ph_shift: (v(out)/v(in))=(-0.408776dB,-17.4406°) at 50
```

What I need is only to extract the ***-17.4406°*** value inside an 'X' variable parameter, because I want to use it in another mathematical expression.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Suppose you could (you can't) -- how do you intend to take that value and use it?

Comment: That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Math functions as atan(x), atan2(x,y), Re(x) or Im(x) can't be used and results reused?

Comment: @BuGu The title is impartial, because it only says how you can "extract" the parameter, which can be done anywhere else. But in the question you mention that you need it reused in the schematic, and that changes the meaning.

Comment: >>>What I need is only to extract the -17.4406° value inside an 'X' variable parameter, because I want to use it in another mathematical expression.<<< Is this value used in the circuit, or for calculating anything else independently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of `.meas` scripts come out as a compact notation, so you can't separate them, at least not within LTspice. You can use the error log with external software and extract the needed values, but then you will still need to manually (or with a batch processing of sorts) edit your schematic, afterwards, because the `.meas` scripts are all run *after* the simulation. So you have three steps, at a minimum: run schematic, extract values, re-edit the schematic.

Comment: Thanks , It would have been so nice if I could do that . Once again thanks for your effort.

Comment: @BuGu To be clear: no SPICE can do that, because of the way the `.meas` scripts are handled: the measuring can only be done after simulation has finished. But if what you want is to adjust the phase *in circuit*, then what you're looking for is a PLL of some sort.

Comment: Why not , I thought if we can get a maximum value or a minimum value of a signal than, we could also get that angle value multipy with sth and get a group delay maybe , or get something completely different .  But as far as I can understand from your response , LTspice doesn't permit that , since the outputs are not accessible by the user .

Comment: @BuGu You can do more measure cards if you want to compute post processed results that depend on other post processed results. For example you can compute the RMS value of one node and divide it by the RMS of another node. But only within one run/step, I believe. If you want dynamic, instantaneous phase feedback within a run, then as a concerned citizen writes, that may be a PLL.

Comment: @BuGu  Sounds like there's some confusion here.  I think you misunderstood the first question asked in the comments under your initial question.  He was asking for more details on what you intend to do with the result and you never clarified.  Therefore, he's assuming you need to reuse the result as a functional parameter in the actual circuit.  If you need to just use it in a subsequent `.meas` statement, you can use the `Mag(x)` and `Ph(x)` functions.  See the LTspice help section titled "Waveform Arithmetic" for more info.  Also see the `.options` help for `meascplxfmt`.

Comment: @SteKulov It's entirely possible. My reason has to do with OP's words "...another mathematical expression", I presumed it's behavioural, or function, or some expression enclosed within curly braces for evaluation in another simulation. But if it's just using the result of a `.meas` for another `.meas` then, as you say, that's very allowed (and there are even some examples in the help: *LTspice > Dot Commands > .MEASURE*).

Comment: Let me clarify it in this case , as you know LTspice outputs a log file and responses you back upon your .op codes and scripts you insert the spice . During or after the simulation I simply want to take the degree value multiply this value with some other constant and put it inside an another parameter and also see this scaled or reformed value inside the log file output .. So is it possible ? and for the examples I tried the Ph() mag() functions but they keep giving "2" parameters values not 1 as the as in post up top .

Comment: @BuGu Then the answer remains: you can't run a `.meas` script during the simulation (only after it has finished normally), and you can't extract the results to be used in the same (or another) schematic with only what LTspice has -- you need external tools (and another simulation). As for the results, themselves, they come in either dB/deg, or re/im (for `.AC` measurements, where the analysis is complex).